# Responsive grid without outer border

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid

I am attempting to create a responsive grid using CSS which separates a collection of icons/tiles by inner-borders (see layout below).

```
CONTAINER | CONTAINER | CONTAINER
---------------------------------
CONTAINER | CONTAINER | CONTAINER
```

I've been able to achieve this using first-child/last-child selectors, but not in a way that scales with additional containers and is responsive.

http://codepen.io/patrickabel/pen/VmRyqQ

Is there a way to accomplish this without JavaScript?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the grid should scale with additional containers and be responsive? How should the grid appear with additional containers? Are the containers added dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you need, but is there any reason not to use a table? Something like this:

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td, table th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:first-child td, table tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 0;
}
table tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
table tr td:first-child,
table tr th:first-child {
    border-left: 0;
}
table tr td:last-child,
table tr th:last-child {
    border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="container">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>F</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Is</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>Test</td>
    <td>Phrase</td>
    <td>:)</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```